# NVMe SSD is visible on Device Manager but not visible in Disk Management

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ssd, bios, nvme

I was using my windows pc all and well but suddenly windows stopped working. I have a usb bootable Ubuntu and with this I wanted to extract my files before formatting the SSD completely but for some reason, it is not listed in `Disks` and does not show it on `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l`. I opened the BIOS options to check what is going on and it is listed as you can find from the attached file: [image]

In BIOS:
I have disabled the secure boot
SATA mode is AHCI
I have switched Legacy OS/UEFI OS modes back and forth nothing is changed. What should I do to reach this ssd and its files, ubuntu commands are also accepted.

**EDIT:**

I have installed windows to my HDD, I can see it in device manager as **Standard NVM Express Controller**, I updated the driver but still the same condition. I can disable or uninstall too. I just want it to be visible whether from windows or ubuntu usb to be able to format it and use it. It is also not visible in disk management (as well as disks in ubuntu)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Anything that boots in a 2018 PC should boot in UEFI mode. Any preinstalled Windows 8.x or newer is in UEFI mode. You shouldn't have changed the modes and it has nothing to do with it. Secure boot also has nothing to do with booting Ubuntu live and retrieve files. If the drive isn't detected in Ubuntu plus *suddenly windows stopped working* then it's probably dead. **After replacing the drive make sure to re-enable UEFI only and Secure Boot before booting the Windows installer**.

Comment: And our title has nothing to do with the actual problem you asked about.

Comment: UEFI also did not show it. @ChanganAuto Also, if its completely dead, it shouldn't be listed in bios right?

Comment: No, not necessarily. It can be detected by UEFI and yet inaccessible and unusable.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Its a laptop, will it be okay to just leave the dead ssd inside? :D

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem other than a slot that can't be used. But, just in case, try booting Windows installation media (properly made, either the official media creation tool or Rufus with UEFI/GPT option or Ventoy (multi-boot tool)) to see what it says about the drive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it does not show with windows installation media too

Comment: Well, I would guess that's your answer.

Comment: @JeredriqDemas it is possible that the controller on the drive is working and reporting its standard drive information, but the flash chips are dead. It would explain the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Is the 256GB ADATA the drive you've been "looking for"? Is it listed in `lspci`?

Comment: @TomYan sadly it was not. I updated the question with windows installed and I can observe it in Device Manager

Comment: @Mokubai I updated the question with windows installed and I can observe it in Device Manager

Comment: @JeredriqDemas that just further proves that you have a functional drive *controller* but no underlying storage behind it. The flash storage on your SSD is dead. If it was important then send it to a data recovery service and hope for the best but they will probably be expensive. Otherwise pull it out of the machine, throw it in the bin and get a new one.

Comment: A modern SSD consists of two chips on a board. There is a "controller" that takes in PCIe and can talk to NAND flash storage devices, then the other chip is the NAND storage. If the link between those two chips is broken, or the flash itself has died then you will get the behaviour you are seeing. If the controller dies then *everything* goes away, but just because the flash might die doesn't mean that the controller will die at the same time.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks a lot for the great explanation, can you post it as an answer; I will accept it. All makes sense now and I really think my ssd died :D